# Improper Advertising Identifer Usage

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, idfa

When I try to submit my app, it says that I have not indicated the IDFA's usage in itunesconnect. Now, I know this question has been asked many times before, but I've never had any problem with this until Apple just recently changed the layout of itunesconnect. Before, there used to be a "Ready To Upload Binary" button where I can check the IDFA box, but I've spent half an hour clicking everything in itunesconnect and I can't seem to find any "Ready to Upload Binary" button or anything about the IDFA. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Just came across the same issue. After you get that warning, go to the itunes connect app page. Scroll down to submit build, press the plus button and select the build you just uploaded. Hit save. Hit Submit app for review. Then tick using IDFA. Done.

Comment: This is just a warning and you can simply ignore it. You will receive a mail from Apple about the warning. Since they have changed the order of when to supply information about IDFA, you simply just supply the information after the upload. If you go to Prereleases in iTunes Connect, your binary should be uploaded. Just wait for it to be processed and then you can use the build for the release AND include IDFA usage.